# Fill in gaps between dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to fill in NULL gaps in my table. EACH ID(x) can have more than one CKD_STAGE but there are some months with null values, I want to fill the the spaces in between with the latest known CKD_STAGE. Here's what I have so far.

```
SELECT DISTINCT DOS, x, CKD_STAGE, REF_YEAR
FROM #CKD_MM

 DECLARE @MAXDOS INT = (SELECT MAX(DOS) FROM #CKD_MM)
 DECLARE @MINDOS INT = (SELECT MIN(DOS) FROM #CKD_MM) 

 Update #CKD_MM
 set CKD_STAGE = @MAXDOS
 WHERE CKD_STAGE is null
      AND DOS BETWEEN @MAXDOS AND  @MINDOS
```

My logic is to find distinct x id and look at the dates(DOS) and CKD_Stage for each unique ID. Look at the maximum and minimum date for each ckd_stage and fill in the gaps in between with the maximum value. The program runs but I'm still getting NULL values.

Here's a snapshot of what the table looks like with one of the id's

```
DOS     x         CKD_STAGE REF_YEAR
201405  480000000   2       2014
201510  480000000   NULL    2015
201504  480000000   NULL    2015
201506  480000000   NULL    2015
201512  480000000   NULL    2015
201511  480000000   NULL    2015
201409  480000000   2       2014
201509  480000000   3       2015
201507  480000000   NULL    2015
201404  480000000   NULL    2014
201501  480000000   NULL    2015
201411  480000000   NULL    2014
201402  480000000   NULL    2014
201503  480000000   NULL    2015
```

So I need all the NULLS with dates before 201509 to be 2, and All after 201509 to be 3. I have 1000's of records so I need this to work over a range of different ids and different CKD_STAGES.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to set the null value column to be 2 if it is before dos column value 201509 and 3 if it is after 201509.

```
Update #CKD_MM
 set CKD_STAGE = case when dos>=201509 then 3 else 2 end
 WHERE CKD_STAGE is null
```

Comment: No, I need it to work over all range of values for the date and CKD_STAGE, I have 100's of records, the table above is just a snapshot of 1 record (one ID).

Comment: You can write case statements for those range values. you can provide your scenario so that I can help you out for your range of values

Answer (score 0):

using `apply()` to get the previous and next non `null` values for a given `x`

```
select 
    t.dos
  , t.x 
  , coalesce(t.ckd_stage,prev.ckd_stage,nxt.ckd_stage) as ckd_stage
  , t.ref_year
from t
  outer apply (
    select top 1 i.ckd_stage
    from t i
    where i.x = t.x
      and i.dos > t.dos
      and i.ckd_stage is not null
    order by i.dos asc
  ) nxt
 outer apply (
    select top 1 i.ckd_stage
    from t i
    where i.x = t.x
      and i.dos < t.dos
      and i.ckd_stage is not null
    order by i.dos desc
  ) prev
order by t.dos
```

as an `update`

```
update t
set ckd_stage = coalesce(prev.ckd_stage,nxt.ckd_stage)
from  t
  outer apply (
    select top 1 i.ckd_stage
    from t i
    where i.x = t.x
      and i.dos > t.dos
      and i.ckd_stage is not null
    order by i.dos asc
  ) nxt
 outer apply (
    select top 1 i.ckd_stage
    from t i
    where i.x = t.x
      and i.dos < t.dos
      and i.ckd_stage is not null
    order by i.dos desc
  ) prev
where t.ckd_stage is null

select * 
from t 
order by dos
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/YFTM98118

returns:

```
+--------+-----------+-----------+----------+
|  dos   |     x     | ckd_stage | ref_year |
+--------+-----------+-----------+----------+
| 201402 | 480000000 | 2         |     2014 |
| 201404 | 480000000 | 2         |     2014 |
| 201405 | 480000000 | 2         |     2014 |
| 201409 | 480000000 | 2         |     2014 |
| 201411 | 480000000 | 2         |     2014 |
| 201501 | 480000000 | 2         |     2015 |
| 201503 | 480000000 | 2         |     2015 |
| 201504 | 480000000 | 2         |     2015 |
| 201506 | 480000000 | 2         |     2015 |
| 201507 | 480000000 | 2         |     2015 |
| 201509 | 480000000 | 3         |     2015 |
| 201510 | 480000000 | 3         |     2015 |
| 201511 | 480000000 | 3         |     2015 |
| 201512 | 480000000 | 3         |     2015 |
+--------+-----------+-----------+----------+
```

Comment: This doesn't work, it's still producing NULL values.

Comment: @C.AJ combined my previous answer into one.